# How do I take related posts (by category) with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a question on how to fetch the related posts of a particular post by category using Eloquent. I know how to do it in pure MySQL but am sure Eloquent will have nicer alternative to it.

My tables are: posts categories post_category (pivot)

I have made the neccessary Eloquent connections, so I want to do something like: `$post->categories()->posts()->exclude($post)->get()`.

Of course this won't work. I get an error on posts() because "Builder doesn't have a method posts()", but hopefully you get the idea. How would you do it with Eloquent?

Comment: It's probably going to be something like `Category::whereIn($post->categories->lists('id'))->posts()->get()`.

Comment: Yeah, something like this could work, but its giving me an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what you want to achieve, bot probably you want to get:

```
Posts::whereIn('id', $post->categories()->lists('id'))->whereNot('id',$post->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the confusing parts about Eloquent's relations is that the method on a model that defines the relation will bring back a relation object when called like you're calling it:

```
$posts->categories();
```

To return a collection of category models attached to your posts you should use something like this:

```
Post::find(primary key of post)->categories;
```

Or get all posts and iterate through the models individually:

```
$posts = Post::all();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post->categories;
}
```

Here's a resource I found very helpful in learning to use Eloquent's relation methods: http://codeplanet.io/laravel-model-relationships-pt-1/

Comment: I can't call `->categories` on a collection. It doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: You're correct. You'll need a model of your Posts to work with. See my edits for my corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get my related posts by category and searched on google and got here.
I made this, and it worked fine.

```
   public function getSingle($slug){
        $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        $tags=Tag::all();
        $categories=Category::all();

        $related= Post::where('category_id', '=', $post->category->id)
            ->where('id', '!=', $post->id)
            ->get();

        return view('blog.show')
            ->withPost($post)
            ->withTags($tags)
            ->withCategories($categories)
            ->withRelated($related);         
    }
```

In my **view('blog.show')**

```
$post->title
$post->content

//related posts
@foreach($related as $posts)
  $posts->title
  $posts->category->name
@endforeach
```

I don't know if this is the right way, but it works for me. I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you define a ‘relatedposts’ relation where search for posts with the same category id?
Then you can simply do `$post->relatedposts`...

You’re making it overcomplicated imo...

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple category (Pivot ex:RelPortfolioCategory)


Portfolio Model:

```
public function getCats(){
        return $this->hasMany(RelPortfolioCategory::class,'portfolioID','id');
    }
```

controller:

```
public function portfolioDetail($slug){
        $db = Portfolio::where('slug' , $slug)->with('getCats')->firstOrFail();
        $dbRelated = RelPortfolioCategory::whereIn('categoryID' , $db->getCats->pluck('categoryID'))->whereNot('portfolioID' , $db->id)
            ->with('getPortfolioDetail')->get();
        return view('portfolioDetail' , compact('db' , 'dbRelated'));
    }
```